# can't import models from django custom seed command

Tags: django-models, python-3.6, django-2.0, makemigrations

I have a django 2.0.6 project running on python 3.6. I'd like to create a `manage.py` command that seeds the project database with initial data using `faker` and `factory_boy`. I have the subcommand working and printing to `stdout`. When I try to import the models I get the following error

```
RuntimeError: Model class cb3p.events.model_utils.Link doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.
```

The models are fine, however: `python manage.py makemigrations` works, the app works.

Moving the models into the same app as the project doesn't help. Stripping the models down to the point where they only contain a single table with 1 field doesn't help. Moving the import inside the commands `handle` method doesn't help.

Comment: How did you define your command, as raw Python code, of in a `Command`?

Comment: See here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-management-commands/

Comment: @Amit could you show your model and the management command you wrote?

Answer (score 0):

Oops, looks like I figured it out. When you have a command that accesses an app it looks like it needs to extend [AppCommand](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-management-commands/#django.core.management.AppCommand)